# Only one housekeeper cleans an entire floor?

Tags: simtower

In building my Hotel, I was trying to follow some guides on the internet which say you should build one housekeeper station per hotel floor and not build stairs or service elevators since you don't have a limit on cleaning stations apparently.

My issue with this though is that only one housekeeper from each station cleans each floor in the morning. This becomes problematic when half of the floor is not yet cleaned and guests are moving in for the night.

Is this an expected issue that has some sort of workaround?

Comment: It's been a while I played. I would suggest 1) to build less rooms per floor (build vertically instead of horizontally) and 2) to add more housekeeper stations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One housekeeper per station will clean a floor.  For example, six floors of hotel rooms, one housekeeping station per floor.  If you build a service elevator connecting all six floors, six housekeepers will clean each floor, they just originated from different stations.

My experience has been that 2-3 stations are good enough for 6 floors.  It sounds like your hotel may be wider, so you may need more.
I believe you need service elevators, stairs will not work.  They're not dragging those carts up and down stairs.

If you don't have six floors of hotels, then you can watch the housekeepers sit in their stations and not do anything. Lazy.

Comment: Quite annoying, too! I think I used to go by that philosophy earlier, so I'll probably start using service elevators then. Would you typically block the six floors of hotel rooms ontop of each other then?

Comment: I usually did the six floors together.  Depending on how far you want to plan ahead, I suppose you could leave room for the twin/deluxe hotels as well, or just do another block.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is super old, but I always read house keepers will not use stairs in this game. They will actually use up to three sets of regular stairs to reach a floor!

This means you could have one cleaning station for three floors of hotel rooms. Whether or not all the rooms will get cleaned is dependant on how many rooms per floor; each house keeper will clean up to 19 rooms and only one house keeper from the station will be assigned per floor.

It seems to be pointless to use stairs for housekeeping, you're gonna end up needing that service elevator.

Comment: Thank you for adding!